# Combine mongodb query using $cond

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
if (override) {
    await ProjectModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            _id: projectId,
            users: { $elemMatch: { user: userUpdate.user } }
        },
        {
            $set: {
                'users.$.role': userUpdate.role
            }
        }
    );
}

await ProjectModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        _id: projectId,
        users: {
            $not: { $elemMatch: { user: userUpdate.user } }
        }
    },
    {
        $addToSet: { users: userUpdate }
    }
);
```

Here userUpdate is an object containing user (object id) and role (string).

If override is true and userUpdate.user is present in users ,update role else retain previous value of role. If userUpdate.user is not found in users then add to set.

**is there a way to combine both queries into 1?**

Appreciate all the help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you post sample json documents and corresponding expected output?

Comment: Would be difficult, because you have different conditions. `{ $elemMatch: { user: userUpdate.user } }` will **optionally** update (most likely) only one document. `{ $not: { $elemMatch: { user: userUpdate.user } } }` will update almost all documents. In the first command you update `users.$.role` whereas in the second you update `users` with a different value. These two updates are fairly different.

Comment: You can use an Update with aggregation pipeline to achieve this - however it will be a large statement with lots of conditions that might be less readable in MQL than it is in code. A sample of the document would be very helpful.